# Swift - UDP Receive & Send

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, udp, esp8266

I am trying to send and receive UDP packets between an iPhone app and an ESP8266. I have several ESP devices all communicating just fine, but I can not for the life of me create anything for iOS that will see or send anything. I have tried SwiftSocket, CocoaAsyncSocket, UDPBroadcastConnection, Apple's new NetworkExtension/NetworkConnection library, all to no avail.

The target device IP address is 192.168.4.1, and the port we are using is 4210. The target device is sending out broadcasts on 255.255.255.255. I can see these from my macbook.

Trying to send or receive packets to any IP from my app has been unsuccessful. I have tried testing it with the app PacketSender from the mac app store. Can anyone recommend an actual functional working example of a solution? I don't care at this point which of the above libraries is the one being used, I just need to move some data.

One step I did ensure: The app in Xcode has the Network Extension capabilities enabled.

Here is an example from my UDPBroadcastConnection attempt:

```
// in viewDidLoad()...
// ...
//broadcastConnection declared globally

broadcastConnection = UDPBroadcastConnection(port: 4210, handler: { (ip, port, response) in
            print("Received from \(ip):\(port):\n\n\(response)")
        })
```

Nothing sent or received here.
With NetworkConnection:

```
connection = NWConnection(host: "192.168.4.1", port: 4210, using: .udp)

        connection!.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            switch (newState) {
            case .ready:
                print("ready")
            case .setup:
                print("setup")
            case .cancelled:
                print("cancelled")
            case .preparing:
                print("Preparing")
            default:
                print("waiting or failed")
                break
            }
        }
        connection!.start(queue: .global())

        connection!.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
            print("Got it")
            print(data)
        }
```

Never receives anything. Does however go from preparing to ready state. Runs the receive message line, doesn't print anything. Never prints any further information about state. Tried to run the receive message off of a button action to try more than once, still does not seem to want to receive.

It may be worth noting that the app is able to receive its own sends when running on the simulator, but there doesn't appear to be any connection out of the device (to/from PacketSender, for example)

Comment: You don't need a Network Extension to send and receive UDP packets.  You should edit your question to show one of your attempts.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your reply. I just posted a few examples of some of the things I've tried to do. Let me know if this helps clarify. Thank you very much

Comment: Try using connection!.receive(...), *not* connection!.receiveMessage(...). The ESP8266 might not be marking its datagrams complete.  ReceiveMessage waits until it's marked complete, receive gets what's available.

Comment: Mark, did you get anywhere with this? I am having the same problem. Sends ok? But unable to receive anything on iOS device? Tried both receiveMessage and receive. Both never seem to fire?

Comment: @user3069232 Hey, I did, using GCDAsyncUdpSocket. This was a little while back but this was the resulting code I used which did work. I hope that it still works now (I imagine it should.) It's ugly and was quickly hacked together for a presentation, so sorry about that. https://github.com/markypizz/Chill-Senior-Capstone-Project/blob/master/Test2/Test2/ViewController.swift

Shoot me a message on GitHub if you need a hand. I'd go in more depth now but I'm traveling at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     
    var connection: NWConnection?
    var hostUDP: NWEndpoint.Host = "192.168.4.1"
    var portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port = 4210
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lableRedy: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lableReceive: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lableMessege: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
     
    }
    
    //MARK:- UDP
      func connectToUDP(_ hostUDP: NWEndpoint.Host, _ portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port) {
          // Transmited message:
       
        let messageToUDP = "7773010509060602040701000001010d0a"
          self.connection = NWConnection(host: hostUDP, port: portUDP, using: .udp)
          self.connection?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
              print("This is stateUpdateHandler:")
              switch (newState) {
                  case .ready:
                      print("State: Ready\n")
                      self.sendUDP(messageToUDP)
                      self.receiveUDP()
                  case .setup:
                      print("State: Setup\n")
                  case .cancelled:
                      print("State: Cancelled\n")
                  case .preparing:
                      print("State: Preparing\n")
                  default:
                      print("ERROR! State not defined!\n")
              }
          }

          self.connection?.start(queue: .global())
      }

      func sendUDP(_ content: Data) {
          self.connection?.send(content: content, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
              if (NWError == nil) {
                  print("Data was sent to UDP")
              } else {
                  print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
              }
          })))
      }

      func sendUDP(_ content: String) {
        let contentToSendUDP = content.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
          self.connection?.send(content: contentToSendUDP, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
              if (NWError == nil) {
                  print("Data was sent to UDP")
                 DispatchQueue.main.async { self.lableRedy.text = "Data was sent to UDP" }
              } else {
                  print("ERROR! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
              }
          })))
      }

      func receiveUDP() {
          self.connection?.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
            if (isComplete) {
                  print("Receive is complete")
                 DispatchQueue.main.async { self.lableReceive.text = "Receive is complete" }
                  if (data != nil) {
                      let backToString = String(decoding: data!, as: UTF8.self)
                      print("Received message: \(backToString)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.lableMessege.text = backToString }
                    
                  } else {
                      print("Data == nil")
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    

    @IBAction func tappedSend(_ sender: Any) {
       connectToUDP(hostUDP,portUDP)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code with host address "255.255.255.255" for broadcast datagram packet and my intention is to server discovery. So the message is sent successfully but I did not receive any message. I tried with iPhone simulator with iOS 14.3 and iPhone 5 with iOS 12 real device. And also I have configured "multicast" entitlement as well. Do you have any idea of why is not receiving messages. Thanks